# jQuery Display More - JsonP Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it limit the amount of callbacks to say 4 and then if you click display more it displays all of them or maybe just display 4 more and then you can click it again.

It'd be cool to have it so it displays the button until all are displayed and then it disappears but thats not essential.

I've tried to work around just a variable like a counter and then each time in the $.each statement I can just add 1 to the counter and use an if statement, or something. Than I could just make it display within a range, for example "1 - $counter" and then each time you click the button "$counter =+ 4" or something.

Any ideas?

Callback:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=path%20of%20exile&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        $("#content").append('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + item.channel.display_name +'" class="trk" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px; text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from ' + item.channel.display_name +' on www.twitch.tv</a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: yes. But load the json just once. If the streams object/array is not to big, i would just append ALL the <objects> and make them (display:none). Then display them (element.show())

Comment: I don't completely understand.

Comment: something like this > http://jsfiddle.net/rWS8V/

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean cracker! But how would I incorporate my callback into this as by default it will display all, not 4. And this script just checks that it is displaying less than 30. This is technically what I asked for but how do I incorporate the callback?

Comment: you see the code on the left side of the fiddle ? give your object a css class and so on...

Comment: Yeah, I tried to but it didn't work out with the script. I'm sure I'm just making some stupid mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/rWS8V/1/

Comment: this does not work because "item" is not defined in this example! check the console

Comment: Ohkk, I messed around a bit. Checked around with console and came up with this. Not sure what to do next. http://jsfiddle.net/rWS8V/4/

Comment: look here > http://jsfiddle.net/rWS8V/5/  I dont know how to stop auto play... auto_play=false is not working !?

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure it out either :/ But thankyou! That works perfectly! But how do I make it display 4 at the beginning and then 4 afterward?

Comment: normaly you have to make an own function for diplaying the objects... but this hack works too http://jsfiddle.net/rWS8V/6/ just simulate a click at the begining!

Comment: Hmm...I'm getting some weird error, it works in jsFiddle but not on my website. Can we take this to chat?

Comment: give me some chat infos and i will connect

Comment: i added you in skype... you can remove your infos